# Regex Pattern Ignoring Spaces

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm using VB.NET regex object and trying to match the following text:

```
(99- 13014- 0127)
```

I want the output to be: 99-13014-0127 (without spaces and parentheses). I also want the matched string to be stored in a group named "field" as it will then be automatically extracted. The problem is that I can't exclude the spaces from the result. In theory, as per MSDN, the non-capturing group "(?:expression)" should work for me "*The noncapturing group construct is typically used when a quantifier is applied to a group, but the substrings captured by the group are of no interest*." However, I'm still getting spaces in the result.

Here is the pattern I'm using:

```
\((?<field>\d{1,6}(?:\s*)-(?:\s*)\d{1,6}(?:\s*)-(?:\s*)\d{1,6})\)
```

The result I'm getting for the above text and pattern is:

```
99- 13014- 0127
```

What is the correct expression to use that gives me: 99-13014-0127 without spaces?

Thanks

Comment: I appreciate the comment but I was looking to do it in one step. The way my application is structured is that each field has a regEx pattern stored in the database and the VB code automatically calls the regex extraction procedure. I was looking for a way to get the required string without changing the VB code. It looks like it can't be done.

Comment: Even Olivier's answer requires a replace, so perhaps you could use an alternative and have another field in the database to indicate that spaces should be removed. Or a nullable field containing the character(s) to remove.

Answer (score 1):

"Non capturing group" means that this expression will not appear in the group collection; however it does not mean that the result will be excluded from other enclosing groups.

Instead, use lookarounds and apply a string replace to the result. The lookarounds look for patterns before and after the pattern of the required result.

```
string result = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=\()\d{1,6}s*-\s*\d{1,6}\s*-\s*\d{1,6}(?=\))")
                     .Replace(" ","");
```

The Regex pattern uses the pattern `(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)` where `prefix` and `suffix` are the surrounding braces `\(` and `\)` and `find` is the pattern for the number. Prefix and suffix are not included in the result. Therefore it is not necessary to capture the result in a named group.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do this:

```
var newStr = "match".Replace(" ","");
```

This will be a good solution as it will not contain spaces and it does the job **without** using `regex`.